# Adding Bluetooth Low Energy to android app with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So, I've created an app and I want to be able to Add bluetooth devices to it (BLE or not). After I've added them, i want to display them in a different activity. I've looked for lots of tutorials(Stackoverflow and others) but couldnt find something specific.

I am a beginner and i used Kotlin to create the app.

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/ble?

Comment: Or: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le As a reminder this site isn't a code writing service. You will have to describe what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but perhaps this [SensorTag sample app](https://github.com/JuulLabs/sensortag) is a simple enough example of what you're looking to accomplish?

It relies on [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) to scan for nearby [SensorTag](https://www.ti.com/tool/CC2650STK)s, then allows you to select one, which navigates you to another `Activity` and connects to it, then displays sensor data.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend to use the rxJava for the BLE Scanning. For scanning the tags for forground and background working fine '

> For view the demo on github [rxAndroidBle_github_demo](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle)

on this library handled all exception.

*I hope this will work for you !*